# Instaling Ironpython for Linux

Tags: ironpython

Can someone please provide a walk through on how to build IronPython for linux (Ubuntu). I could not build the instance mentioned in the documentation at https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/wiki/Building nor can I build the current repo: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2.git

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to build or just use/execute/install IronPython on linux (on mono?)?

Comment: (Excuse me as I was traveling) I want to be able to execute IronPython scripts using command line executing through mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through various documents and the github build file I was able to draft a solution that worked. The steps are as follows.

```
git clone https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2.git

cd ironpython2/

dotnet restore IronPython.sln --packages ./packages

Make
```

-> check `bin/Release/net40 for ipy.exe`
Test it by running `mono ipy.exe`

Else `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release IronPython.sln /t:Clean,Build`
-> check again

Run `mono bin/Release/net40/IronPythonTest.exe`

Create symlink `nano ipy`

```
#!/bin/sh
EXE_PATH=YOUR_PATH
mono $EXE_PATH/ipy.exe “$@”
```

Replace YOUR_PATH with absolute path, e.i.

Make the scripts executable `chmod +x ipy`

```
copy ipy to /usr/local/bin/
```

At the command line type ipy the IronPython interpreter should come up.